# java error: class, interface, or enum expected (multiole packages)

Tags: java, package

I'm currently running through a Java tutorial, now focusing on packages and protected variables. I am supposed to compile an example that shows how code works when using multiple packages. For some reason I am completely unable to get the code to compile. I've even tried copy-pasting the demo code from the tutorial and even that won't compile. Both my own code and the tutorial code throw:

```
java 23: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package bookpackext;
^
1 error
```

Anyone able to see what's wrong here? I've been looking around and everyone who have posted about the same error have been told to double check curlies and methods, I can't for the life of me see anything wrong here.

Thanks in advance!
My own code below:

```
package bookpack; 

public class Book {
    protected String title;
    protected String author;
    protected int pubDate;

    public Book(String t, String a, int d) {
        title = t;
        author = a;
        pubDate = d;
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println(author);
        System.out.println(pubDate);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

package bookpackext;

class ExtBook extends bookpack.Book {   
    private String publisher; 

    public ExtBook(String t, String a, int d, String p) {
        super(t, a, d);
        publisher = p;
    }

    public void show() {
        super.show();
        System.out.println(publisher);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public String getPublisher() {return publisher;}
    public void setPublisher(String p) {publisher = p;}
    public String getTitle() {return title;}
    public void setTitle(String t) {title = t;}
    public String getAuthor() {return author;}
    public void setAuthor(String a) {author = a;}
    public int getPubDate() {return pubDate;}
    public void setPubDate(int d) {pubDate = d;}
}

class ProtectDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ExtBook books[] = new ExtBook[5];

        books[0] = new ExtBook("Book 1", "Author 1", 2013, "Publisher 1");
        books[1] = new ExtBook("Book 2", "Author 2", 2014, "Publisher 2");
        books[2] = new ExtBook("Book 3", "Author 3", 2015, "Publisher 3");
        books[3] = new ExtBook("Book 4", "Author 4", 2016, "Publisher 4");
        books[4] = new ExtBook("Book 5", "Author 3", 2017, "Publisher 5");

        for(int i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
            books[i].show();

        System.out.println("Showing all books by Author 3:");
        for(int i = 0; i<books.length; i++)
            if(books[i].getAuthor() == "Author 3")
                System.out.println(books[i].getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is/are the file name(s) of the java file(s)?

Comment: Are you by any chance just pasting it all into a single java file? Packages are meant to separate the files.

Comment: Do what @DaveNewton said. Also, make sure the package names actually reflect the directories your source files are in.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the replies. Problem was indeed both packages being in one file (Tutorial actually included both in the same file as well..). Problem solved!

Answer (score 5):

You can't put multiple `package` declarations in a single file.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html

> The package statement (for example, package graphics;) must be the first line in the source file. There can be only one package statement in each source file, and it applies to all types in the file.

Note that the error message pinpoints the line in question and says exactly what is wrong. When starting out with any language make sure you have a language reference guide handy–it'll save a lot of time on issues like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The tutorial actually includes both packages in one file. In any case, problem solved. Cheers!